# Using multiple UISplitViewControllers in an app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitabbar

I am looking for the best way to switch between multiple UISplitViewControllers in an iOS App.

I heard Apple does not want UISPlitViewControllers to not be rootViewControllers so I cannot use a UITabBar. Any ideas what I could use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just switch to a new one in code (from a button or whatever) with self.view.window.rootViewController = myNewSplitViewController;

Comment: Is it safe to change the rootViewController during execution ?

Comment: @senly, not sure what you mean by "during execution", but I've done this in several projects, and haven't seen any problems.